# python-click: Adding an option that modifies the behavior of other parameters

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

This question is about the [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) package:

> Click is a Python package for creating beautiful command line
>   interfaces in a composable way with as little code as necessary. It’s
>   the “Command Line Interface Creation Kit”. It’s highly configurable
>   but comes with sensible defaults out of the box.
>
> It aims to make the process of writing command line tools quick and
>   fun while also preventing any frustration caused by the inability to
>   implement an intended CLI API.

I'd like to add a `click.Option` to my `click.Command`, which changes the behavior of the other parameters of that command. Consider the following example:

```
@click.option('--x', default=42, prompt=True)
@click.command
def cli_a(x):
  print(x)


@click.option('--x', default=42, prompt=False)
@click.command
def cli_b(x):
  print(x)
```

If `cli_a` is called without explicitly specifying `x` the user is prompted to provide a value (or confirm the default value with ENTER). If `cli_b` is called without specifying `x` the default value is used without prompting the user.

I'd now like to add a flag `click.Option` that allows the user to choose between one of the above variants (at runtime). So, calling `cli_c --i` would behave like `cli_a` and calling `cli_c` would behave like `cli_b`.

```
@click.option('--i', is_flag=True, default=False, expose_value=False)
@click.option('--x', default=42, prompt=False)
@click.command
def cli_c(x):
  print(x)
```

Is that doable with the current API? Is it feasible?

A similar use-case would be something like an **anwser-all-confimation-prompts-with-yes** flag. Usually this comes up if the cli tool is supposed to be usable interactively by the user and in automated mode via a script or some such thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have come up with following code, which produces the desired behavior:

```
def deactivate_prompts(ctx, param, value):
    if not value:
        click.echo("entering batch mode, deactivating all prompts ...")
        for p in ctx.command.params:
            if isinstance(p, click.Option) and p.prompt is not None:
                p.prompt = None
    return value

@click.option('--i/--b', default=True, is_eager=True, expose_value=False, callback=deactivate_prompts)
@click.option('--x', default=42, prompt=True)
@click.command
def cli_c(x):
  print(x)
```

The idea is to use the callback of an eager option to modify all (other) `Options` of the `Command`.

POTENTIAL WEAK POINTS:

- This is an all or nothing solution, i.e. either all of the prompts are active or none. For my use-case, that's exactly what I wanted, but for others that might not be the case.
- This works only in one direction, i.e. by turning the prompts off. So each `Option` that may or may not display a prompt must be configured as if displaying a prompt.
- If we turn off the prompts, we still need a value for that `Option`, so an alternate value-source is a must. I.e. a default value must be provided.